# Download link for SQL Server Reports add-in for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone provide the download link for SQL Server Reports add-in for Visual Studio 2008 (not Visual Web Developer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the Reporting Services development tools by running the install for SQL Server. You can download a 180 day trial here: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx